# How to add custom field CiviCRM to allow user buy a ticket for multiple events?

Tags: php, mysql, civicrm, civicrm-extension

I'm editing my question to make more clear.

**User Case**
I want to publish an event where the user is able to choose specific package from for the ticket.

I also want to allow my customer to choose a ticket that will allow them to attend more than 1 event.

How can I do this using CiviCRM?

**Idea 1:**
One of my idea is to add a hidden field in the form that will be filled up using javascript if the user choose the ticket for multiple events but I don't want to do this because I want to allow the admin to specify this value when creating the event in the back end.

**Idea 2:**
I am trying to add custom option in the price field when creating the price set so that I can add the number of extra event that I to provide to my customer. So how can I add this? Is this the ideal way of using CiviCRM?

Or is there another way to do this? I've been at this for almost a week but no solution.

I really appreciate any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: please checkout this https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/custom-fields/

Comment: wouldn't this be better at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link Haresh. However there is no option in adding custom field to the price set itself.